# Need to convert an html file with links (reference of snapshots) to a word file

Tags: java, selenium

I need a help with converting the index.html file in target folder after executing selenium tests with snap shots for the failed steps. I need to convert this to a word file. Please give me some ideas

Comment: index.html is the results file which i am creating after test run, please give some ideas to convert this file to a word document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string pagesource = driver.pagesource;
```

after that just convert the string and save it.